# Bored natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is my problem

If $a$ for $n$ times , $b$ for $m$ times , $a,b\in\{1,2,..,9 \}$, $n,m\in \mathbb{N}^*$, $n\neq m$ proof that 
$$
\underbrace{aaa\cdots aaa}_{n\ \small\mbox{times} }\, \cdot\, 
\underbrace{bbb\cdots bbb}_{m\ \small\mbox{times}}\, =
\, \ldots \underbrace{cccc\cdots ccc}_{k\ \small\mbox{times}}\ldots,
$$ 
where $c$ is for $k$ times in the middle.
Example:$$33333333*555555=18518499814815=...99....$$ $$a=3,n=8,b=5,m=6,c=9,k=|m-n|=8-6=2$$
 $$(3,8)*(5,6)-->(9,2)$$

Question is

If we have $(a,n)$ and $(b,m)$  can we find $(c,k)$?
I supose $k=|m-n|$ but I do not know $c$.

Is solved for $99\cdots 99 \, \cdot \, 99\cdots 99=\ldots 99\cdots 999\ldots$ where $k=|m-n|$, any $n$ and $m$.
I need some new ideeas.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. In the RHS, does the $\dots ccc\cdots ccc\ldots$ means any number which have a chain of many $c$ in the "middle" of the decimal representation instead of one that only contains $c$?

Comment: I would recommend rewriting your question for clarity's sake. A and B should be in a similar form to what Aditya suggested. Hint: Notice that 81*11=891, 81*111=8991, 81*1111=89991, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general case is
$$
N = (\underbrace{a\cdots a}_{n})_{10} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a 10^k \quad
M = (\underbrace{b\cdots b}_{m})_{10} = \sum_{l=0}^{m-1} b 10^l
$$

which gives
$$
N M 
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a 10^k \sum_{l=0}^{m-1} b 10^l
= ab \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 10^k \sum_{l=0}^{m-1} 10^l
$$

Those sums are finite geometric series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 10^k = \frac{10^n-1}{10-1} = \frac{10^n-1}{9}
= (\underbrace{1\cdots 1}_{n})_{10}
$$
so we get
$$
\begin{align}
N M 
&= \frac{ab}{81}(10^n - 1)(10^m - 1) \\
&= \frac{ab}{9}\frac{10^n - 1}{9}10^m - \frac{ab}{9}\frac{10^n-1}{9} \\
\end{align}
$$

Assume $n \le m$, otherwise switch $N$ and $M$.

Then for the cases with $d = ab/9$ where $9$ divides $ab$, 
thus 
$((a,b),d) \in \{ ((a,9),a), ((9,b),b), ((3,3),1), ((3,6),2),((6,6),4),((6,3),2) \}$, $d \in \{1,\cdots,9\}$ 
we get
$$
\begin{matrix}
NM &= &(\underbrace{d\cdots d}_{n} & \underbrace{0\cdots 0}_{m})_{10} & - \\
   &  &                            & (\underbrace{d\cdots d}_{n})_{10} & \\
   &= &(\underbrace{d\cdots d}_{n-1} & d-1 &
 \underbrace{9\cdots 9}_{m-n} & \underbrace{9-d\cdots 9-d}_{n-1} & 10-d)_{10}
\end{matrix}
$$

For example
$$
\underbrace{66666}_5 \cdot \underbrace{6666666}_7 
= \underbrace{4444}_4 3\underbrace{99}_2 \underbrace{5555}_4 6
$$
where $d = 4$.

This covers $21$ of $81$ possible cases. For the remaining $60$ cases where $9$ does not divide $ab$ I have no idea yet.

Comment: For the cases where 9 doesn't divide and $ab$ and $m>n$, could we use 
$NM=\frac{ab}{81}(10^n - 1)(10^m - 1)= \frac{ab}{81}(10^{n+m} - 10^n-10^m + 1)$ given that $10^{n+m} - 10^n-10^m + 1$ yields a pattern of $\underbrace{9\cdots 9}_{m-1} 8 \underbrace{9\cdots 9}_{m-n}\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_{n-2}1$, and $81(10^k-1)/9 = 8  \underbrace{9\cdots 9}_{k-1}  1$?

Comment: I don't know yet.

Comment: Is OK mvw but $c=9,$ not $4$ and $k=2$ . That is not important in my problem.I whant to know only what is in the middle of product.Thank You!

Comment: @catnit Those are different definitions. I'll rename it. Yours is the string of $9$-digits, that arises because a [carry operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_%28arithmetic%29) happens accross the string of $0$-digits in the zone of the length difference.

Answer (score 2):

Obsolete:

Your equation can be written as:
$$\frac{10^{n+1}-1}9\frac{10^{m+1}-1}9ab=\frac{10^{k+1}-1}9c\\
\frac{(10^{n+1}-1)(10^{m+1}-1)}9ab=(10^{k+1}-1)c\\$$

Comment: something missing and is not verified for common numbers! achille hui understand problem. I make a revision for clarity.